# How do I remove digits from the middle of a numeric date using bash or applescript?

Tags: bash, awk, applescript, extract, trim

I found a way to extract the creation date of a pdf and I would like to use it as part of the new filename. However, I want the date to be in the format "mmddyy" and it is returning at "mmddyyyy". How can I remove the first "yy" using either bash or applescript?

Here is the code that I am using to get the date to the 8 digit form:

`mdls $f | grep kMDItemContentCreationDate | head -n1 | awk '{gsub("[^[:digit:]]+"," ");print $2$3$1}'`

Is there a way to modify this to only return the 6 digit date or do I need to do something to the 8 digit return?

I have tried assigning variables to different awk commands to extract pieces of the string but that isn't working.

Comment: Please, for testing post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have an `awk` command that parses the date (printed in ISO format `yyyy-mm-dd ...` by `mdls`) it would make sense to adapt that command instead of adding another.

I don't have a mac, so I cannot try this. From what I found, it seems `mdls` prints something like this:

```
$ mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate file.pdf
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2023-01-25 17:25:43 -0200
```

From that output, you extract the separate numbers (the first number`$1` is the year, the second number `$2` the month and so on) and change their order (`print $2$3$1`).

To remove the first two digits of the year (`$1`) you can take the substring starting at the 3rd digit of that number (`substr($1,3)`, assuming that all years have exactly four digits) **or** take the remainder when dividing by 100 (the modulo operator `%` does this):

```
$ mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate file.pdf |
  awk '{gsub("[^0-9]+"," "); print $2 $3 $1%100}'
012523
```

Comment: You can also add the `-raw`option to skip the now unnecessary `kMDItemContentCreationDate =` output.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Socowi - adding the CLI option for creation date removed the *need* for `grep` and `head`, and is the better solution, but I wanted to point out that `awk` still eliminates the need for both in those cases where you don't have the better option of reducing and simplifying your input.

```
mdls "$f" | awk '/kMDItemContentCreationDate/{gsub("[^[:digit:]]+"," ");print $2$3$1; exit}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer feeds the date string to the *date* command rather than *awk* to change its format.

```
mdls file.pdf -name kMDItemContentCreationDate -raw | xargs date -jf "%Y-%m-%d" "+%m%d%y"

--> 012623
```

The source date returned by *mdls* was this:

```
2023-01-24 06:34:05 +0000
```

The date options are as follows:

```
-j prevents the command from changing the computer's date
-f format date (these options do not require a separate dash, hence the -jf)

"%Y-%m-%d" - source date format 
"+%m%d%y"  - output date format of 'month day year' without any divider
```

NB Two quirks… First, I could only manipulate the date component of the timestamp. Second, on my mac, mdls time returns a GMT time (note the +0000 above).

While the time is correct, if any usage of that time does not take the time zone differential into account then the date output could be off by one day -- basically, if it's a new day in London but not here then it will return the London date. Perhaps because of the first quirk, I have been unable to shift the time  using `-v-5H` although I can shift the day using `-v-1d`. Dunno why these issues are intractable but they are for me — maybe it's a shell environment/time zone issue but I can't tell.